# How do I get an ENTIRE webform or element with all form values stored into a string. Not Serialized

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a web form #form1 and many elements are dynamically created, therefor I can't just use searialize. I want to store the form input in localstorage so that when the user submits the form, they can hit the back button, and I can recreate the form 100% where they left off.

This is an internal company tool, nothing super secure required for a public facing site. I want to store the HTML contents from the form including the form itself, that way all dynamic content can be restored.

I've tried `$('#form1')[0].outerHTML` `$('#form1').content()` and many other options in jQuery, but that doesn't give me any filled form values.

I basically want the evaluated HTML of the form id `form1` 100% complete, including all filled out data to be stored in a variable in JS.

This is not a duplicate because no other question I've seen anywhere relates to getting a complete HTML element, and all form values stored to a single string for easy restoration later. This is NOT serialization.

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195065/how-to-send-a-json-object-using-html-form-data

Comment: That's serializing the elements and values, but it wouldn't add dynamic elements back in when I tried to restore the content. I need a full HTML dump, but it needs to include the completed form elements.

Comment: You have to use JQuery to restore the content, getting the inputs by name and set their value

Comment: That won't work. I have dynamically inserted table rows containing form elements. Those dynamic rows will not be restored. I just need the HTML as it is, with values filled out on the screen stored into a string.

Comment: Are all informations temporally stored in input fields?

Comment: @Cerbrus, please unclose this. This is not a duplicate because no other question I've seen anywhere relates to getting a complete HTML element, and all form values stored to a single string for easy restoration later. This is NOT serialization.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you're asking for a solution that's a combination of [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) and [`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/).  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the information from the input fields with .val() and store it in arrays for AJAX querys or another process operations:

JS example:

```
var key = [];
var value = [];
$("input").filter('.form1').each(function(){
    key.push($(this).attr('id'););
    value.push($(this).val());
});
```

You can also store the information in one array and split the key and the value like CVS with a semicolon.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('<div>').append($('#formId').clone()).html();
```

I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652763/how-do-you-convert-a-jquery-object-into-a-string).

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/myrluk3/ns9u6krz/1/)**.

Comment: Didn't work when storing it in a string. Thanks though! I have a solution that works, I'll post below.

Comment: Please post it, I am curious