# Save html form input to json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

```
<div class="email">
<section class="subscribe">
<div class="subscribe-pitch">
</div>
<form action="#" method="post" class="subscribe-form" id="emails_form">
<input type="email" class="subscribe-input" placeholder="Enter email for newsletter" >
<button id="email_submit" type="submit" value="send" class="subscribe-submit"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
</form>
```

I need to save the input data from a simple email form to a json file.I think I do that with javascript. Can someone help step by step please? I am novice

Comment: Is the json file downloaded by the user or is it sent somewhere else?

Comment: What kind of server is this email form (or the HTML page containing it) hosted on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery)

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2276477/3029422, it also has an example

Comment: You need to save it on the server? If that's the case, Javascript doesn't have anything to do here. Maybe PHP (or whatever server-side language the server is using) will help you (with something like `json_encode()`). But, as always, if you have a Javascript array and you need to get the JSON **string** in Javascript, `JSON.stringify()` could help you. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify

Comment: @MariusP. It just says to save it to a json file.I guess on my site root folder..I dont really know what it means

Comment: @cjs1978 It is my own home.html file.The psd for the site says to save the data from the email form to a json file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

let student = {
    name: 'Mike',
    age: 25, 
    gender: 'Male',
    department: 'English',
    car: 'Honda' 
};

let data = JSON.stringify(student);  

fs.writeFileSync('file.json', data, finished);

function finished(err)
{
    console.log('success');
}
```

Comment: But this would work only with Node and not if the code is executed into the browser...

Answer (score 9):

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/kifozu/edit?html,console,output)

Using Serializing we can save input html form to JSON output

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function(e){
     var jsonData = {};

   var formData = $("#myform").serializeArray();
  // console.log(formData);

   $.each(formData, function() {
        if (jsonData[this.name]) {
           if (!jsonData[this.name].push) {
               jsonData[this.name] = [jsonData[this.name]];
           }
           jsonData[this.name].push(this.value || '');
       } else {
           jsonData[this.name] = this.value || '';
       }


   });
   console.log(jsonData);
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : "action.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : jsonData,

    });
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
 Send Form's data as JSON
</div>

<form id="myform" type="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Ajax Form  </legend>
    <p>We would love to hear from you. Please fill out this form</p>
    <div class="elements">
      <label for="name">Name :</label>
      <input  required="required" type="text"  value="Girish Kumar Santhu" name="fname"  size="20"  />
    </div>
     <div class="elements">
      <label for="Age">Age :</label>
      <input required="required" type="number" value="32" id="age" name="age" size="10" />
    </div>  
    <div class="elements">
      <label for="pro"> Profession :</label>
      <select name="pro">
   <option value="Student">Student</option>
   <option value="Engineer" selected="selected">Engineer</option>
   </select>
    </div>      
    <div class="elements">
    <label for="Gender">Gender: </label>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" checked="checked" id="r1"> Male 
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" id="r2"> Female 
</div>  
    <div class="elements">
      <label for="hobby">Hobby :</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="Sports" id="ch1" checked="checked"> Sports 
  <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="Coding"  id="ch2"> Coding 
   </div>

    <div class="submit">
       <input type="submit" id="btn" name="btn" class="btn" value="Submit" />
    </div>
    <span class="elements">Press "Ctrl + Shift + J" to see sent JSON in console: <span>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Pls your answer is useful for me. But how can I save this to file not console at this point. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, it's quite simple:

```
var formData = JSON.stringify($("#emails_form").serializeArray());
```

If you want to store `formData` in a JSON file, you need to post it to the server (e.g. per AJAX) and save it. But in that case, you can simply post the form und convert it to JSON on the server itself.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195065/how-to-send-a-json-object-using-html-form-data).