# Sending data with Json and javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, forms

I want to collect the data with Json when the button is pressed. Could someone send me a example with the best way to do this? I used JS to make a function on the button but I can't figure out how to use Json.

This is my HTML code:

```
<body>
 <div class="formclass">
        <form method="post" name="myform">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
            <input id="city" type="text" name="city" placeholder="City">
            <button type="button" id="insert">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
     </div>
   </body>
```

Bas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a JSON object using html form data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195065/how-to-send-a-json-object-using-html-form-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var formData = JSON.stringify($("#myForm").serializeArray());

[How to send a JSON object using html form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195065/how-to-send-a-json-object-using-html-form-data)