# Not able to map submit button to "/submit" api call in thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, java, html, thymeleaf

This is my web service method inside a Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public @ResponseBody Response submitAppication(@RequestBody String submitString) {
    System.out.println("***************************  Entering for submit part ********************************");
    Response response = Response.status(400).build();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(submitString);
        jsonObject.put("event", "submit");

        SMEvent sme = new SMEvent(HttpMethod.POST, jsonObject);

        String tid = Util.getTid(jsonObject);
        response = handleEvent(sme, getVerificationType(tid), tid);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        //TODO log some exception here
    } finally {
        return response;
    }
}
```

This is my HTML page with a form:

```html
<div th:if="${InstaPanState==1 and InstaPanStateStatus==0}">
    <body>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/submit}" method="post">

        <label><b>Name</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" name="name"/><br/><br/>
        <br/>
        <label><b>Father's Name</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Father's Name" name="fname"/><br/>
        <br/><br/>
        <label><b>Contact Number</b></label>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Contact Number"/><br/><br/><br/>

        <div class="clearfix">
            <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="submitbtn">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    </body>
</div>
```

When I click the submit button it should call the mentioned web service method.

Currently I got the following exception and it is not calling the web service.

> Looking up handler method for path /submit
>         2017-09-25 15:41:36.189 DEBUG 5405 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] 
>         .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from 
>          handler [null]: 
>         org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content 
>         type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens what should be the solution for this , I have also tried by adding <form action="#" th:action="@{/submit}"  method="post" enctype="APPLICATION_JSON" >
Please help me as i am new in spring

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens tried and it is coming into the method but showing is a bad request
since i am accepting it as string

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195065/how-to-send-a-json-object-using-html-form-data explain how to send json data from html form, otherwise you have to change server implementation using `RequestMethod.POST` and `@RequestParam` for each parameter that form send.

Answer (score 1):

You are POSTing an HTML form, but the web service is configured to consume JSON.

Change the web service method to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody Response submitAppication(
          @RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> formParams) {
    // TODO: Extraction logic here
}
```

Comment: I got this : 
{"statusType":"BAD_REQUEST","entity":null,"entityType":null,"metadata":{},"status":400}

with the solution what you suggest

Comment: Sure...
 @RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
   consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public @ResponseBody Response submitAppication(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String,String> submitString) {
       
        Response response = Response.status(400).build();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(submitString);
            jsonObject.put("event", "submit");
///// Some code
        return response;
    }

Comment: @User120909 I had an error in `consumes`, use `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE`

Comment: MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE This mediatype is not supporting for intelij
it is showing error

Comment: @User120909 you should also remove `@Produces`, because that mixes Java EE and Spring. The `RequestMapping` annotation itself has a `produces` field, use that one.

Comment: I have tried by removing this and i got bad request issue:
{"statusType":"BAD_REQUEST","entity":null,"entityType":null,"metadata":{},"status":400}

Comment: Code is : 
@RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public @ResponseBody Response submitAppication(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String,String> submitString) {
        System.out.println("***************************  Entering for submit part *********************************" + submitString);

        Response response = Response.status(400).build();

Comment: @User120909 looks like you're deliberately returning status 400. Does the `System.out.println` statement print anything? That would mean the code works.

Answer (score -1):

Please try the below.

```
  @PostMapping(value = "/submit")
        public ResponseEntity<UserSetail> createUser( @RequestBody UserDetail user) 
        {
    new ResponseEntity<UserSetail>(user, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
```

Comment: what is this ??? i am not able to understand what you want to suggest .
Please help me with my code .....