# Passing data with ajax and read it with Request.Form[""]

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I try to pass parameters into `aspx.cs` page from `js` script. When I omit:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

in ajax request I get by `Request.Form["ORDER"]` sth like `{%7b%22ORDER_ID%22%3a126333%7d}`. It means that this data comes to `aspx.cs`, but it is not decoded.

[image: WITHOUT CONTENT TYPE]

When I add `contentType` I get nothing in request.

[image: WITH CONTENT TYPE]

Below I attach request.

It is important to read parameters from `Request.Form["ORDER"]` in `aspx.cs`;

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ ORDER_ID: orderKeyId }),
        dataType: "json",
        url: sUrl,
        success: function (data) {
            var s = 0;
        },
        error: function () {
            var s = 0;
        }
    });
```

Comment: WebForms is designed to work with form-urlencoded data by default, not JSON. If you want to use JSON you'll need to deserialise it from the `Request` object manually, or write your own model binder.

Comment: you have to parse the json once in aspx.cs file

Comment: post `aspx.cs` file data

Comment: @Ameya Deshpande It is just simple PageLoad and then (Request.Form["ORDER_ID"]

Comment: @Rory McCrossan I do not need to use JSON. I just need to read it from Request.Form, not Request.QueryString

Comment: That's what you're already doing. The problem is purely because you're sending JSON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a JSON object using html form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195065/how-to-send-a-json-object-using-html-form-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Rory McCrossan comment, below ajax state worked:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    data: "ORDER_ID=" + encodeURIComponent(orderKeyId),
    url: sUrl,
    success: function (data) {
        var s = 0;
    },
    error: function () {
        var s = 0;
    }
});
```