# `Page not found (404)` in POST endpoint with JSON data

Tags: forms, post, f#, websharper

I'm trying to use a `POST` endpoint that accepts `JSON` data from a `HTML` form, but only get `404 - Page not found` as a result, unless I add another endpoint without the payload.

So I can create a demo project from template and make small changes to test this issue:

```
cd /tmp
dotnet new websharper-web --name Demo --language F#
cd Demo
dotnet run   ## Ok!
```

Edit `main.html` to add the form:

```
<div class="container">
    ...
</div>
<form method="post" action="/demo" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <button type="submit">Post</button> 
</form>
<footer class="footer">
...
</footer>
```

Add to `Site.fs` the code to handle the form request:

```
type Data = { name: string }

type EndPoint =
    | [<EndPoint "GET /">] Home
    | ...
    | [<EndPoint "POST /demo"; Json "data">] Demo of data: Data
    | [<EndPoint "POST /demo">] DemoFallback

[<Website>]
    let Main =
        Application.MultiPage (fun ctx endpoint ->
            match endpoint with
            | ...
            | EndPoint.Demo data ->
                printfn "Data: %A" data
                Content.Text "Ok demo with post data"
            | EndPoint.DemoFallback ->
                Content.Text "I don't expect this route"
        )
```

Run the project again:

```
dotnet run
```

And from the browser I get `I don't expect this route`, but from `curl`:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -XPOST "http://localhost:5000/demo" \
  -d '{ "name": "me" }'
```

or with different `content-type`:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  -XPOST "http://localhost:5000/demo" \
  -d '{ "name": "me" }'
```

both yield:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 29 Jan 2019 12:57:19 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Ok demo with post data
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: @AMieres: Not quite, because if I remove the `DemoFallback` path, the browser returns me a `(404) Page not found` after submitting the form.

Comment: You are right, according to the documentation it tries the options in the order declared and uses the first one that matches. Which means the form of the JSON the browser sends is not `{ "name" : "..."}`

Comment: @AMieres: Either the form and the type already have one field: (`<input type="text" name="name" />`) and `type Data = { name: string }`.

Comment: According to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195065/how-to-send-a-json-object-using-html-form-data the form is not sent in Json format unless you serialize it that way.

Comment: @AMieres: You are right in your last comment. It has worked using `[<FormData("arg1", "arg2", ...)>]` from the docs, instead of `[<Json "data">]`. Add it to an answer so I can approve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An HTML form does not send the information in Json format instead it uses url-encoded which is similar to the query parameters in a url except that they go in the body of the request and not the URL, for instance if you have 2 fields User & Password:

```
User=John&Password=123456
```

In order to receive the data from the form you need to use the `[< FormData >]` attribute:

```
type Data = { [< FormData >] name: string }
```

and indicate the EndPoint lile this:

```
 | [< EndPoint "POST /demo" >]  Demo of data: Data
```

Comment: I was confused about those `form` parameters, so thank you very much for helping me understand and solve it.

Comment: No problem, it helps me understand it too.