# Strange data shape when sending JSONed form by AJAX

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, flask

I'm trying to send a form using Ajax as JSON to a flask server, the problem is that the shape of the request I got on the server is strange.
I'm following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195065/how-to-send-a-json-object-using-html-form-data#answer-22195193) and my code is as follows:

**Form**

```
<form action="/Go" role="form" method="post" id="myForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input autofocus class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" required type="text" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required type="text" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Your Age" required type="text" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="height" name="height" placeholder="What is your height" type="text" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer shorten-form">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Jquery**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Go",
    data: JSON.stringify($("form#myForm").serializeArray()),
    dataType:"json",
    contentType:"application/json",
    success: function (html, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Now using `request.get_json()` on the server and printing the result appears to be like this:

```
[{'name': 'fname', 'value': 'Shadow'}, {'name': 'lname', 'value': 'fax'}, {'name': 'age', 'value': '12'}, {'name': 'height', 'value': ''}]
```

While I'm expecting something like this:

```
{'fname': 'Shodow', 'lname': 'fax', 'age': '12', 'height': ''}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you also inculde the general structure of your form?

Comment: It would be useful to inspect the data you're sending before sending it

Comment: @keysl Updated the question

Comment: @peeebeee I inspected the request in Firefox and it is sent as it appears on the server, in a list with names and values

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. This is how `.serializeArray()` works, compare [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/). If you want name-value pairs, sending JSON has no benefit. Just to a regular form POST (use `.serialize()` and don't set the content-type to JSON), I'm sure Flask will turn that into exactly what you expect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery)

Comment: You can also transform the object before sending it to the server, or transform it after receiving it on the server, but it's really not worth the hassle. Think about *why* you want to use JSON format here in the first place and if there is any benefit beyond "it feels more modern". In the end you're sending *a string* to the server, whether it is JSON format or URL-encoded format is completely irrelevant. When there are two options to come to the same result, pick the simpler one.

Comment: @keysl when inspecting the request in Firefox, the parameters are sent as i want, but the problem is that at the server i must use `request.get_json()` since there's another applications using the API and they send the request as JSON. `request.get_json()` returns None if i did what you said.