# JSON Data in an HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

I have looked many places and even here on stack overflow, but I cannot find information on sending JSON data in HTML / JS in a PUT request. I have tried many things, but I have not yet found a way.

I have went online and found that you can use stringify() and XMLHttpRequest, I have tried the following with no success.

```
    <script>
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var theUrl = "/";
        xmlhttp.open("PUT", theUrl);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ "test": "my data"}));
    </script>
```

I currently am having to create a website, but I am currently required to send a PUT request to another website containing JSON data. Down below is a very simple representation of what I am trying to do.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="https://www.theOtherWebsite.com" method="PUT">
       
      <!-- JSON data to send upon pressing submit -->

      <button type="submit" name="button">submit</button>
      
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

If anyone has information on a solution that would be great.

If I have to use a server, I could, but I would still need to somehow send this request to a third party website with the JSON data which I have not been able to find out how to do either.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you share what you've tried so far? Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195065/how-to-send-a-json-object-using-html-form-data

Comment: <form>'s will always submit as form data - if you want to send JSON you'll have to use [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) / [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054165/using-put-method-in-html-form

Comment: Also why would you use HTML form method, use JS fetch PUT: https://medium.com/swlh/restful-api-design-get-post-put-patch-delete-a-walkthrough-with-javascripts-fetch-api-e37a8416e2a0

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @ikiK and @Turtlefight for the answers. I couldn't find that method anywhere until you guys mentioned it, works.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      fetch("127.0.0.1:3000", {method:'PUT', headers:{
        'content-type': 'application/json'},
         'body': JSON.stringify({TestNumber:1, TestText: 'text'})
       });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is a very simple sample of what I used and it works great, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

- i think that http method not makes any deferant you can use any method you wants to but just check your code first because you are forgot to use event like `onloadend` or `onreadystatechange` anyway I will try to give you an example and i hope it's work for you

```
var obj = { "test": "my data"};
 obj = JSON.stringify(obj);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onloadend = function (e) { 
   console.log(e)
}
xhr.open("PUT", url, true)
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
xhr.send(obj)
```