# datatables with input field - get data as array

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

Good Morning,

I am working with [datatables](https://datatables.net) and this [example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/form.html)

Here my test:

```js
        
        var t = $('#example').DataTable( {
            rowReorder: true
        } );
        
        $('button').click( function() {
            var data = t.$('input').serialize();
            console.log(data);
            return false;
        } );
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.11.3/r-2.2.9/rr-1.2.8/datatables.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>


<button type="submit">Submit form</button>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Fname</th>
            <th>Lname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fname" value="Max" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lname" value="Mustermann" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fname" value="Max" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lname" value="Mustermann" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>    


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.11.3/r-2.2.9/rr-1.2.8/datatables.min.js"></script>

    
</body>
</html>
```

If I click the button, I get this output:

```
fname=Max&lname=Mustermann&fname=Max&lname=Mustermann&fname=Max&lname=Mustermann
```

But I would like to get a array like this (jQuery or php solution):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fname] => Max
            [lname] => Mustermann
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fname] => Max
            [lname] => Mustermann
        )

)
```

I have no idea how I can realize it.
Can you help me please?? :)

** UPDATE **

Result (Rory)

```
Array
(
    [example_length] => 10
    [fname] => Array
        (
            [0] => Max
            [1] => Max
        )

    [lname] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mustermann
            [1] => Mustermann
        )

)
```

Comment: this will give another structure. please look at my first post

Comment: You're right - apologies. In that case the only way to build the data structure you require from the HTML would be to use JS then send the array via AJAX to your PHP backend.

Comment: The following may help: [How to send a JSON object using html form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195065/how-to-send-a-json-object-using-html-form-data) and [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery).